# LARAVEL : Add key and value in single array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a single array of data, I want to add a key and it's value in same array . Here  in `addedPost` I want to add key `favouritePost` and it's value is `$favouritePost` after `product` key. How can i do this ?

Here is my query:

```
$addedPost      =   Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
                ->whereId($postData['post_id'])
                ->first();
    $favouritePost  = PostFavourite::isAlreadyAdded($postData['post_id'], Auth::id());

    return  [
       'status_code'     =>    $status_code,
       'message'         =>    $message,
       'PostDetails'     =>    $addedPost
    ];
```

What I get in response :

```
{
"PostDetails": {
    "id": 289,
    "user_id": 12,
    "product_id": 2,
    "demand_or_supply": "Demand",
    "description": "edited1",
    "status": "Expired",
    "created_at": "2018-06-22 07:35:27",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-05 06:42:56",
    "product": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Diamond",
        "icon": null,
        "status": "Active"
    } 
}
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
{
"PostDetails": {
    "id": 289,
    "user_id": 12,
    "product_id": 2,
    "demand_or_supply": "Demand",
    "description": "edited1",
    "status": "Expired",
    "created_at": "2018-06-22 07:35:27",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-05 06:42:56",
    "product": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Diamond",
        "icon": null,
        "status": "Active"
    },
    "favouritepost": {
         "id": 8,
         "post_id": 289,
         "user_id": 12
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: Same as `product`, you can use `favouritepost` with `with` function.

Comment: what if i want `$favouritePost` use this ?

Comment: @Javed its should be as simple as adding a new property on the `$addedProduct` object. `$addedPost->favouritepost = $favouritePost` have you tried this?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin yes it is working perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: Your `$addedPost` is not an array but a Eloquent Collection. There are multiple possibilites to do this. The easiest one is to union an Array with the Collection.

```
$union = $addedPost->union($favouritePost->toArray());
```

For every other solution please take a look at the Laravel Documentation. It's pretty easy to understand.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Edit: Though I missed the `->first()` inside the question just use the solution  already mentioned. `->first()` returns a `StdClass` Object, so you can handle it like it:

```
$addedPost->favouritepost = $favouritePost;
```

That property favouritePost is added to $addedPost object in that case. There's no need for any method call again.

Comment: Union possibly would make a new query on the addedPost instance of Query builder since `$addedPost` is not a collection, see the `first()` method used after the first query. I tested it on Laravel 5.4 and I want to be sure this is not some strange behavior that is fixed on L5.6

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin You are right. I missed the `->first()` inside the question. @ op just go with his solution to add `$favouritePost` as attribute to `$addedPost` !

Comment: sorry I heavily edited your answer to effect the right example you may be referring to. I hope I didnt change any of your idea in the process.

Comment: I observe that the `first()` return a `Builder` class instead of `StdClass` although indeed StdClass is close

Comment: Interesting. Laravel Doc tells that it returns a `StdClass` instance. Gotta check that later. Edit: Maybe `Builder` behaves like a `StdClass` object and thats why

Comment: It'd return StdClass if You use the `DB` facade and then you cannot chain any other method to the first object. But if you use Eloquent (wrapped around query builder as well), then you have an instance of the Model that can further do other operations like `->load('myOtherRelation')` -  Lazy Loading. I may not be entirely correct too. It'd be an interesting topic to find out.

Answer (score 0):

first you store all the values which you are returning in one associative array then  use array_push() to add new key/value in that array.After all you just return that array.

Comment: $existing_array = array('status_code'     =>    $status_code,
       'message'         =>    $message,
       'PostDetails'     =>    $addedPost,'favouritePost' => $favouritePost);     
  return $existing_array;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$addedPost` is a laravel collection you can simply do:

```
$addedPost = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
            ->whereId($postData['post_id'])
            ->first();
$favouritePost  = PostFavourite::isAlreadyAdded($postData['post_id'], Auth::id());

$addedPost->put('favouritepost', $favouritePost);

return  [
   'status_code'     =>    $status_code,
   'message'         =>    $message,
   'PostDetails'     =>    $addedPost
];
```

Comment: See the last method call on `$adedPost` is `->first()` hence it cannot be a collection most likely its Query `Builder` and method `put()` does not exist on Query `Builder` except there's difference now in L 5.6 (tested this on L5.4 though)

Answer (score 0):

for adding key value in object

```
$object->new_key="value";
```